# How do I store and access a list of jquery elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to store a jquery object so that I can manipulate it in the future. I am however failing at this task and would be glad if someone could point me in the right direction.

What I am trying to do is first store a list of resources:

```
var allresources = $('.resource-list');
```

After that, I do some ajax operations that take a long time on the server, which is why I would like to store all the data in memory. AJAX returns me an array of ids: [1,2,3]. I want to clear the content of the initial div .resource-list and populate it only with the ones that match my ids. I am trying something along these lines but am not really getting anywhere:

```
var sortResources = function(data){
  $('.resource-list').html('');
  $.each(data, function(index, value){
    $(allresources.children('.filter-resource[data-id="'+value+'"]')[0]).appendTo($('.resource-list'));
  });
}
```

Thanks

Comment: So, what is not working? Any console errors?

Comment: No console errors, I get no html rendered on screen.

Comment: Did you check the structure of `data`? Is it a collection/array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

allreasource variable is just a reference to the dom elements.

You are erasing those elements before filtering them (with $('.resource-list').html(''); ).

I suggest you to append the "valid" content to a temporary div, than replace the content of .resource-list

Comment: Perfect, thanks. That was silly of me. This works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is with these snippet.

`$('.resource-list').html('');` will literally empty the `.resource-list` from DOM.

Now [**children**](https://api.jquery.com/children/) method allows us to search through the children of these elements in the DOM tree, but but in the mean time `.html('')` has emptied the the relevant DOM

What alternatively you can do

```
var allresources = $('.resource-list');
var sortResources = function(data){
var _virDom = ""
  $.each(data, function(index, value){
   // Not sure what exactly is the DOM, so using span for demo
  _virDom = '<span class = "filter-resource" data-id="'+value+'"></span>'
  })
  $('.resource-list').html("").append(_virDom)

  });
}
```